# Looking for SQL constraint: SELECT COUNT(*) from tBoss < 2

Tags: sql, count, constraints

I'd like to limit the entries in a table. Let's say in table *tBoss*. Is there a SQL constraint that checks how many tuples are currently in the table? Like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from tBoss < 2
```

Firebird says:

> Invalid token.
> Dynamic SQL Error.
> SQL error code = -104.
> Token unknown - line 3, column 8.
> SELECT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your database have triggers?  If so,  Add a trigger that rolls back any insert that would add more than 2 rows...

```
Create Trigger MyTrigName
For Insert On tBoss
As
    If (Select Count(*) From tBoss) > 2
       RollBack Transaction
```

but to answer your question directly,  the predicate you want is to just put the select subquery inside parentheses. like this ...

```
  [First part of sql statement ]
  Where (SELECT COUNT(*) from tBoss) < 2
```

Comment: Depending on DB & isolation level, wouldn't you need to lock the table? For example if there is one row already and two transactions inserting.

Comment: I "think" that because each Insert would place locks on the rows it is inserting, which would not be released until the trigger had finished, and allowed the transaction to be committed, that a table lock would not be necessary, but I'm not sure ofthis last point.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this with a check constraint and a scalar function. Here's how I built a sample.

First, create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
 (
   MyTableId  int           not null  identity(1,1)
  ,MyName     varchar(100)  not null
 )
```

Then create a function for that table.  (You could maybe add the row count limit as a parameters if you want more flexibility.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyTableRowCount()
RETURNS int
AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @HowMany int

    SELECT @HowMany = count(*)
      from MyTable
    RETURN @HowMany
 END
```

Now add a check constraint using this function to the table

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
 add constraint CK_MyTable__TwoRowsMax
  check (dbo.MyTableRowCount() < 3)
```

And test it:

```
INSERT MyTable (MyName) values ('Row one')
INSERT MyTable (MyName) values ('Row two')
INSERT MyTable (MyName) values ('Row three')
INSERT MyTable (MyName) values ('Row four')
```

A disadvantage is that every time you insert to the table, you have to run the function and perform a table scan... but so what, the table (with clustered index) occupies two pages max. The real disadvantage is that it looks kind of goofy... but everything looks goofy when you don't understand *why* it has to be that way.

(The trigger solution would work, but I like to avoid triggers whenever possible.)

Comment: Hi, how do I add parameter to the `MyTableRowCount` function? Lets say I want to include `WHERE` in my count statement.

Comment: It depends on what you are checking for in the `WHERE` constraint. I recommend making this a separate SO question.

Answer (score 1):

To find multiples in a database your best bet is a sub-query for example: (Note I am assuming you are looking to find duplicated rows of some sort)

> SELECT id FROM tBoss WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM tBoss GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1 )

where id is the possibly duplicated column

Comment: My thought pattern (and assumption) were following this tract, but insufficient data in the question to isolate what the real goal is at least as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tBoss WHERE someField < 2 GROUP BY someUniqueField
```

Comment: Thank you, but the whole table should not contain more than 2 entries. So what's the solution without a *where*? I get an error.