# SQL: How to enforce functional dependency using constraints?

Tags: sql, relational-database, unique-constraint, relational-algebra, functional-dependencies

Assume we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs
    (
      JobID INT PRIMARY KEY ,
      AssignedUser VARCHAR(10) ,
      Zone VARCHAR(10)
    )
```

The constraint we need to enforce is this: make sure that no user is assigned jobs in more than one zone, that is, there is a functional dependency `AssignedUser => Zone`.

How to enforce this in SQL? Unfortunately, this is a legacy table and we cannot change its structure, but we are allowed to create constraints to enforce integrity.

Comment: What about a unique index on assigned user.  they should only appear in the table once right?

Comment: Nope. A user may be assigned several `Jobs`, but all of them should be in the same zone.

Comment: trigger that validates in a procedure the functional dependency before update/insert.  The trigger can't easily be bypassed and the procedure can raise an error preventing the duplicate entry.  I can't see how to do this with just a index. such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631070/looking-for-sql-constraint-select-count-from-tboss-2

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? In SQL Server you could enforce this with an indexed view.

Comment: @MartinSmith It's MS SQL Server 2012. What is an indexed view?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic14149-8-1.aspx  add a constraint using a user defined function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work. You may want to add a where clause excluding `Zone IS NULL` depending on the desired semantics for that.

```
CREATE VIEW V 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
  SELECT AssignedUser, 
         Zone, 
         COUNT_BIG(*) AS C 
  FROM   dbo.Jobs 
  GROUP  BY AssignedUser, 
            Zone 

GO 

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX 
  ON V(AssignedUser)
```

Comment: So, an insert or update in `Jobs` will automatically check all the indexed views you define elsewhere on `Jobs`? Is it because of `SCHEMABINDING` or it happens for all views?

Comment: @Saintali It is because of the index. That will get maintained when the underlying data changes and have the uniqueness condition checked.

Comment: Isn't this some kind of security hole? Why should I be able to define an indexed view on _your_ table?

Comment: You'll need appropriate permissions. Probably `references` permissions on the table I would have thought.

Comment: What an ingenious trick. How come I have never seen it before?!

Comment: I tried to outsmart you and use a `DISTINCT` keyword instead of the `GROUP BY`. But SQL Server told me to copy your answer _verbatim_. Are you the person who developed this feature at Microsoft? :)

Comment: @Saintali Indexed views have [many limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) unfortunately, including `Distinct`.