# How to set constraint to limit duplicate values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question about how to set a constraint of a table to denied insertion of duplicate values in MySQL.
For example, here is a table to store the fruit and its price:

```
"apple"  | $30 
"apple"  | $30 
"apple"  | $30 
"orange" | $20 
"banana" | $30
```

The constraint limits the maximum insertion of the same fruit name is 3.

So when I insert one more apple, it won't be happened:

```
"apple"  | $30 
"apple"  | $30 
"apple"  | $30 
"apple"  | $30 
"orange" | $20 
"banana" | $30
```

I see MySQL command has UNIQUE to reject any duplicate values but it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: You can't create a constraint like this unless you add an extra column "version".

Comment: Not exactly the same but this previous answer may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631070/looking-for-sql-constraint-select-count-from-tboss-2]

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a constraint like this unless you add an extra column "version". If you do, you can see how two constraints do the trick:

```
create table t (
  fruit varchar(10) not null,
  version int not null check (version between 1 and 3),
  price int,
  constraint uq1 unique (fruit, version)
);

insert into t (fruit, version, price) values ('apple', 1, 30);
insert into t (fruit, version, price) values ('apple', 2, 30);
insert into t (fruit, version, price) values ('apple', 3, 30);
insert into t (fruit, version, price) values ('apple', 4, 30); -- fails
insert into t (fruit, version, price) values ('apple', 3, 30); -- fails
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6928e46c5fa82ea8597695296a9931c2).

**Note**: It would be up to your app to include some logic to produce the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Comment: Note MySQL 8.0.16 is required for support of [CHECK constraints](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody's help, I have figured out the way to do this now!
And I would like to share my answer here, hope it would be helpful to someone who have the same issue.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRTIGGER trigger1
      BEFORE INSERT ON Fruit
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM Fruit
          WHERE fruitName = New.fruitName
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
        )
        THEN
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NO MORE THAN THREE';
        ENDIF;
      END$$
```

So this trigger can will show error when user want to insert the 4th record of the same fruit name.  Remember to use `DELIMITER $$`, it will change ; to $$ to end the statements.  You can use `DELIMITER ;` to change it back.